# Python cx_Oracle connection with failover oracle url

Tags: python-3.x, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I have the failover database connection 
Some thing like below:

```
CONSTR =
(DESCRIPTION =
(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Host Name)(PORT = Port Number))
(LOAD_BALANCE = YES)
(CONNECT_DATA =
(SERVER = DEDICATED)
(SERVICE_NAME = Service Name)
(FAILOVER_MODE =
(TYPE = SELECT)
(METHOD = BASIC)
(RETRIES = 180)
(DELAY = 5)
```

Is it possible to establish oracle connection in python using cx_Oracle imports.

using python 3.5

currently using

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(user="myuser", password="mypass", dsn=dsnStr)
```

to connect the db.

and below statement returns the CONSTR (as mentioned above)

```
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("hostName", "port", "SIDNAME")
```

My requirement is to directly use the CONSTR (with failover URL) in cx_Oracle.connect().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted by the [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module.html#cx_Oracle.makedsn) the third parameter is for the SID. If you are intending to use a SERVICE_NAME you need to do the following instead:

```
dsnStr = cx_Oracle.makedsn("hostName", "port", service_name="service_name")
```

If you have defined something in your tnsnames.ora file, however, you can just that name directly. You don't have to use makedsn().

Also, you can use EZ connect syntax as in the following:

```
cx_Oracle.connect("user/pw@host:port/service_name")
```

Hopefully one of those options will help you out!

Comment: For better or worse, some developers like embedding the full connection string in the application instead of putting it in a `tnsnames.ora` file. In this case you could do: `dsnStr = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=HostName)(PORT=PortNumber))(LOAD_BALANCE=YES)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=ServiceName)(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=SELECT)(METHOD=BASIC)(RETRIES=180)(DELAY=5)"`

Comment: Will it be applicable if i have multiple address like (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=Hostname2)(PORT=Portnumber2)..) too 
and using cx_Oracle.connect()

Comment: Anything that can go in tnsnames.ora is legitimate syntax for cx_Oracle's connect string. You can test with SQL*Plus, too.